# Calculating page view log for each user in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have collection which has this structure

```
{
UserId:Guid,
Timestamp:123,
Url:''
}
```

I want to set an interval e.g. 30 seconds to find if customer was in a specific Url or not. if customer was in this page for more than 30s this means that he/she visited this page. 
How can I achieve that in MongoDB?

Comment: Do u check it every 'n' seconds or planning to have another column signifying the end time?

Comment: You may subtract the Timestamp attribute with the Current timestamp to extract the difference in seconds

Comment: yes, I check it every n seconds. A user may visit 'x' different pages and spend time in each page. I need to calculate all of that.